# Concatenate string from an array

Tags: batch-file

I want to concatenate the string in the array inside the for loop. Once it get concatenate it should do some task and then it go to the another variable in the array. Please let me know how to do it. Give me some examples.

Here is the code I am trying to execute.

```
@echo off 
set topic[0]=USB
set topic[1]=hello
set topic[2]=mic 
set topic[3]=Operators 
set file = C:\Users\User\Android_Studio_Projects

for /l %%n in (0,1,2) do ( 
    set file=%file% CD\!topic[%%n]!
)
pause
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to be carefull of whitespace before and after `=` when setting variables, also, to use `delayedexpansion`, you need to enable it. You are also trending on the line with whitespace in setting variables, always enclose your variable set in double quotes, like I did below. Try this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "topic[0]=USB"
set "topic[1]=hello"
set "topic[2]=mic"
set "topic[3]=Operators"
set "file=C:\Users\User\Android_Studio_Projects\"

for /l %%n in (0,1,3) do ( 
    echo cd %file%!topic[%%n]!
)
pause
```

You do not need to set `%file%` again inside of the loop seeing that nothing changed. This will only display the command to you, to cd to each directory, just remove `echo` in the loop.